# I am trying to understand the behavior of a pulse

Tags: capacitor, parasitic-capacitance

I have this pulse [image]

This is the observed data. I have a LTSPice model that needs to be matched as close as possible to the observed data I need to match the e area of from 350 to 500 ns, because the pulse is not returning to zero. The thought is that there is a parasitic element behaving as a cap or inductor. [image: area that needs to be understood better] in this close up, the circles are the observed data the blue line is the LTSpice data and the red line is the curve generated in R  from the lm () function for a third order polynomial.
I am not sure that is the correct model for this part of the curve. as it gives me this information when I run the coefficients. At this point I am kind of lost because I have been asked to give the equation to describe it

```
Call:
lm(formula = y_100 ~ poly(x_100, 3, raw = TRUE))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2080.10  -372.44   -40.37   342.17  1412.65 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 -2.030e+06  7.050e+04  -28.79   <2e-16 ***
poly(x_100, 3, raw = TRUE)1  1.424e+04  5.196e+02   27.40   <2e-16 ***
poly(x_100, 3, raw = TRUE)2 -3.327e+01  1.272e+00  -26.17   <2e-16 ***
poly(x_100, 3, raw = TRUE)3  2.590e-02  1.034e-03   25.06   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 584.6 on 296 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9627,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9623 
F-statistic:  2547 on 3 and 296 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> coef(fit3_df_200)
                (Intercept) poly(x_200, 3, raw = TRUE)1 
              -2.733113e+06                1.914600e+04 
poly(x_200, 3, raw = TRUE)2 poly(x_200, 3, raw = TRUE)3 
              -4.467164e+01                3.469908e-02
```

I am a data analyst who is assigned to give a mathematical representation of that part of the graph. I use R to model it and zoom in on the area. If I can give the engineers an equation that represents that area they can use that to eliminate the parasitic. I have asked the people in data science if they had thoughts but they get hung up on that its happening over time. Time series is for events that happen repeatedly anyway I digress.

Comment: Do you think we can give you a useful answer based on the information you have provided? What is the source of this pulse (you mention a square wave but only show a single pulse)? What is the circuit? What is the LTSpice model? How close a match is close enough? I think you can see where this is headed. We would like to help but you need to provide a better description of what you are doing.

Comment: I am not really sure what exactly you would need. But I see what you mean. I am a data analyst assigned to help an engineer understand this pulse. Sorry I called it the wrong thing,yes a pulse.  I have graphed the pulse in R. But The component is huge it is comprised of multiple elements: caps, inductors, and mosFETs. If you needed to model a certain area of a pulse to understand the behavior of an unknown component what approach would you use? The people in data science get hung up on that it is based on time but its not really time series as the pulse only happens once.

Comment: How long were the measurement leads (not counting the scope)? This could be transmission line effects. I sometimes see similar plots when I look at a clock on a PWB after the signal has traveled a short distance. If the negative driver is strong, it may be under-damped. If the positive driver is a little weaker it may be over-damped.

Comment: The only thing that makes this question relevant to EE SE is that one of your axes is labelled 'V'. The best thing to suggest is to just do a high order polynomial fit of that curve. if you were hoping for someone to help you understand what caused that glitch waveform, you need to give way more information about the circuit in question. otherwise, you might as well post the number '3' and ask what equation produced it

Comment: Are you trying to model that curve with a polynomial? Coming from a circuit I would expect an exponential A(1-exp(-t/tau) superposed with a damped sinusoidal oscillation. You can estimate tau and A from the data, fit that simple exponential, then subtract your data and you will be left with the damped oscillatory contribution.

Comment: @SredniVashtar A  is a the coefficient ? is its taken from the slope of the curve? do you have a webpage that could give more more info this equation. I am not an EE by training,  I just work for them.

Comment: A is the distance between the baselines. In your first picture it is about 4.8 squares (approx 180V). Tau, the time constant can be estimated as the intercept of the tangent at the start of the rise (approximately the -180V, 330ns point) with the top baseline (the 0V line). Lookup any circuit theory book with R L C circuits, the exponential approach to a step or square wave is all over the place.

Comment: @alittleloopy ops, I wrote 180V, it should have been 120, possibly a tad less.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

To me, your LTspice (blue) model seems not to be far away from the real data (circles). If you closely look at the real data, you see a sine component with approx. 30ns period whereas your model seems to have about 5-10ns period.

So you might want to increase the Cs or Ls in your model in order to get a lower resonance frequency and to get a better match.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose you applied a step function at the input over an RLC system, you can estimate parameters with the levenberg marquardt algorithm. That way you get realistic value of R, L, C and see then variation of R and C to dampen the oscillation.

As Sredni Vashtar, the equation of a rlc system is of the following form:
V(t) = A - A exp(-t/tau) sin(wt + phi_0)

In a nutshell, the slope is in the order of RC and the oscillation period about L/R. Those values allows you to have a first estimation to start the algorithm.

Then to see the the variation in LTspice you should add a step param command...